# The type initializer for 'ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook' threw an exception

Tags: c#

```
using ClosedXML.Excel;

class XLSXWriter : BExporter
    {
        private readonly string _fName;

        public XLSXWriter(string fileName)
        {
            _fName = fileName;
        }

        public override void Export(IEnumerable<AnimalData> animals)
        {
            var workBook = new XLWorkbook(); <---Throws an exception

            var workSheet = workBook.Worksheets.Add("MySheet");

            workSheet.Cell("A1").Value = "Hello World";            

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(_fName, FileMode.Create);
            workBook.SaveAs(fs);
            fs.Close();          
        }
    }
```

Just trying this library `ClosedXML.dll`, and it throws an exception can't figure out what could be the problem.
I get the `_fName` from the `savefiledialog`.
Ideas anybody?

Comment: OK, I am having this exact exception, but the Project both has a reference to DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll, plus the DocumentFormat.OpenXml namespace is imported.  I still can't figure out why this exception is throwing!

Comment: The inner exception shows (where the DLL does exist in this path):<br>...<br>Attempting download of new URL file:///<project-path>/bin/x86/Debug/DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll<br>Attempting download of new URL file:///<project-path>/bin/x86/Debug/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll<br>Attempting download of new URL file:///<project-path>/bin/x86/Debug/DocumentFormat.OpenXml.EXE<br>Attempting download of new URL file:///<project-path>/bin/x86/Debug/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/DocumentFormat.OpenXml.EXE<br>

Comment: Sorry I am not sure, but if it helps, all i have done is referenced DocumentFormat.OpenXml, ClosedXML and used only ClosedXML.Excel.

Comment: I have all kinds of strange issues with ClosedXML. 1-No Pivot Table support; 2-Out of Memory exceptions with only a few thousand rows, about a dozen or so columns, not a lot of data; 3-Seeming to follow the Out of Memory exception, the type initializer exception.  Since ClosedXML does not seem to be supported by a strong community, we are opting to use Excel API instead.  Bummer, I found ClosedXML to be a really intuitive way of generating XLSX books without Excel app.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thought would delete this post, but might help someone in future....All i had to do was reference one more DLL DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll . Works perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

I had fixed the same error after updating closedXML library. In other words, if ClosedXML and OpenXML are updated packages then this error will not occur.